# Include a correlation value in web_global_verification

Tags: correlation, loadrunner

I'm using Load Runner VuGen 11.5, I use the web_global_verification function to display the error that occurs during running the script, sometimes strange errors appeared and I cant reproduce them as I don'n know what are the data cause the fault. 
so I would like to include a value comes from a correlation in a web_global_verification method -if possible- to identify,once happens, the data caused the failure and if that is not possible, kindly help me of how to solve such issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by saving the correlation value in a string then getting the string value in a Web_Global_verification() function this will look like the below.

lr_save_string(lr_eval_string("Exception Thrown on Username : {Username} / Password: {Password},"ExceptionData");

```
    web_global_verification("Text/IC=<Exception>",
                    "Fail=Found", 
                    "Search=ALL",
                    "ID={ExceptionData}",
                    LAST);
```

Comment: I think you are missing a `"` char.